# Node.JS, Angular.JS, MySql,Express.JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js, express

Developing a contacts list application using MySQL, Angular, Node and Express. Unable to Edit, Update in the following code. Could someone please complete the EDIT and UPDATE part.
Really a beginner, and most of this application has been developed with the help of a tutorial on youtube.

The following is written in Mongo DB. How should i convert this in order to fetch data from MySql.

**SERVER.JS**

```
app.get('/contactlist/:id', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    db.contactlist.findOne({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function (err, doc) {
        res.json(doc);
    });
});
app.put('/contactlist/:id', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(req.body.name);
    db.contactlist.findAndModify({
        query: {_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)},
        update: {
            $set: {
                name: req.body.name, 
                email: req.body.email,
                number: req.body.number
            }
        },
        new: true
    }, function (err, doc) {
        res.json(doc);
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert it in order to get data for MySql, you should look this ORM: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/
This orm is very well documented.
Sequelize will allow you to fetch data from mysql, postgresql and the synthax is really simple to handle with.
Try with this orm and if you have some difficulties, write your test and method.